# from ppadb.client import Client - Syntax Error

Tags: python, android, bots, adb, bluestacks

```
from ppadb.client import Client
```

I am not able to use any adb library out there. I can install them with pip
but Pycharm will give me a syntax error, saying no Module named ppadb.

Can someone please help me?

I tried every adb library I could find. None of them worked for me

Comment: There is no `ppadb` package known https://pypi.org. Which adb package have you installed? Have you read the package documentation before trying to us eit?

Comment: I installed the pure-python-adb package, adb shell and some more. 
But none of them worked for me, even though I saw people on youtube doing it.

Comment: What OS, Python, ADB version and so do you use? Is the adb installed using Android SDK?

Comment: Python version is 3.9.6. OS is Windows 11. And I dont know about ADB Version.

I thought I just have to install the python libraries for ADB, so I do not afk Android SDK.

My goal is to send clicks to Bluestacks via ADB

Comment: adb consists of two parts, the client and the server. some python packages just execute adb client (require adb.exe in PATH or full path), others directly implement adb protocol and don't need client. But they all need adb server. Check if adb is included in Bluestacks and start it using `adb start-server`.

Comment: Are you sure the same python is used by pip and pycharm?

Answer (score 2):

The package you are looking for is called "pure-python-adb".

I ran into the same problem while watching a youtube video where the same import was made.

You can find the package here: https://pypi.org/project/pure-python-adb/

After installing, I had to activate the developer options in my android emulator to use the ppadb methods in python.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other server you need to start the server

```
class startDaemon:
    # try:
    start = subprocess.run(['daemon/adb.exe', 'start-server'])
```

Of course you need the `adb.exe` and `adbwinusb.dll` to run it then after that it will open a

> server 127.0.0.1 port 5037

So when you run these

```
client = AdbClient(host, port)
client.devices()
startDaemon.start
# enter code here
```